# URL Redirection of MP3

Tags: actionscript-3, mp3, redirect, forwarding

So, here's the problem:

I have a flash game where MP3 files need to be externally loaded when the user plays a game.  The problem is that I may change where the MP3s are hosted.  This would normally be fine, just upload a different SWF with the new URL to the MP3s.  The problem is that I can only post the swf once, because it will be uploaded to 1000+ sites and I can't go through them all and upload new ones.  I need a way to redirect the URL to the hosted MP3.

One way for me to do it would be to host the redirection myself, but the game will be extremely popular (i hope) and I was wondering if there was a redirection service out there so that I'd put in:

```
URL: "redirectURL.com/35kskdfji2jdi"
Which would redirect to:  "hostedURL.com/myMP3.mp3"
```

Is there any way for me to do this without just handling the redirection through a server that I rent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the URL in a XML / Text file on your site , or even in a database. Make the best of it and use the database to get some stats on your game :)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure my site can handle the traffic, it's a really low end linux box that I pay $10/month for.  Would I be able to handle that many requests?

Comment: I don't mean to do some advertising here but for 10$/month you could get a host like Dreamhost that should be able to handle this kind of traffic. Furthermore, users wouldn't be browsing your site and make loads of requests , it's only a one time request to get the mp3s url. You could probably optimize that by saving the URL data in a SharedObject so that further requests are not needed, be careful to implement some form of method in order to ensure that the URL is up to date , if you ever plan to change it again!